# Cefsharp DevTools - zoom in

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, cefsharp

I am trying to zoom the **devtools** window.

I know how to zoom the browser window itself, but I am unable to zoom in the devtools.

changing **ZoomLevel** does not effect the devtools window.

EDIT: ctrl +/- does not work.

thanks

Comment: Ctrl Shift `+` and `-` (and similar on Mac).

Comment: @wOxxOm I Wish! not working.